# php ссылка на переменную в значении элемента массива

Tags: php, массивы

Уважаемые специалисты прошу помощи, помогите добавить ссылку на переменную в значение элемента массива.

```
$cnt_att = 8; //общее количество попыток
$att = &$cnt_att;
$status[8] = array('error', "Неверный код подтверждения, осталось $att попыток", 5000, 8);

$cnt_att--;
echo $status[8][1]; //Неверный код подтверждения, осталось 8 попыток

?>
```

Выдает: 8 попыток, а должно стать 7, как сделать?

Вот упрощенный пример:

```
<?php

$cnt_att = 8;
$att = &$cnt_att;
$mes = "Неверный код подтверждения, осталось $att попыток";
$cnt_att--;
echo $mes; //Неверный код подтверждения, осталось 8 попыток

?>
```

Тоже не работает

Comment: вы сначала создаете статус с ошибкой, а уже после вычитаете переменную.  `$cnt_att--;` данный код поставьте перед `$mes = "Неверный код подтверждения, осталось $att попыток";`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, в статусе ссылка на переменную

Comment: В момент создания статуса переменная равна 8, это значение и подставляется в текст. Сделайте что @ЕвгенийНиколаев пишет.

Comment: @Эникейщик благодарю, просто ситуация упрощенная, нужна возможность изменять после, как добавить ссылку на переменную в строку, что-то на подобии `"Неверный код подтверждения, осталось" . &$cnt_att. " попыток";`

Comment: Зачем она нужна такая возможность? Формируй строку каждый раз перед тем, как выводить и в ней всегда будет текущее значение.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, есть большой массив статусов, хотел чтобы все они располагались в одном месте. Если без вариантов, то придется как Вы посоветовали

Comment: Если вы обернете это дело в класс и функции, то у вас получится более менее то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ещё с помощью буферизации вывода *(если требуется менять количество именно в  сообщении, и вы по каким-то причинам не можете реализовать правильно)*:

```
ob_start();

$cnt_att = 8;
$mess = 'Неверный код подтверждения, осталось {att} попыток';
echo $mess;
$buffer = ob_get_clean();

echo str_replace('{att}', --$cnt_att, $buffer);
```

Comment: Спасибо Эдуард, буферизация мне не обязательна, но вариант с плейсхолдером очень интересный, благодарю, воспользуюсь.